# Used PS1 "slim" (PSone) freezes on boot

Tags: repair, sony-playstation

I got a PSone ("PS1 slim") for $5 off Facebook. Real dirty, didn't have any of the cables. So I take it apart, clean it real good. I take my universal power pack and my PS2 AV cables and plug it in. Everything goes fine for a while, the game boots up and I start playing it. Then the video looked like it was inverted, and the audio cuts out. The PSone crashes. I turn it back on and it freezes on the boot screen. I took it back apart and cleaned it out with alcohol. Still doesn't work. I'm thinking it could be the power pack?

What are the steps I can take to determine if this is something I can fix myself?

Comment: Do you mean"slim" as in the one Sony branded "PSone"? Might be a useful detail in terms of troubleshooting.

Comment: Yes, jdv, thats exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 8):

I bet you have a dirty lens or faulty optical drive.  Try cleaning the diode with a Q-Tip and a electronic lens cleaning solution.  It's also possible that the entire drive is broken or dirty.  Does the PS1 read any other discs like audio CDs?  It might need an entire spindle hub or optical drive replacement.

Maybe some of the tips in this [iFixit troubleshooting guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Wiki/PlayStation_Troubleshooting#Section_Game_does_not_load_skips_or_freezes) will help.

Comment: Would a optical drive from a fat ps1 be compatible with a slim?

Comment: @Justin I'm not sure, but I would bet there are at least some technical differences between the optical drives between each PS1 version, even if they were subtle.

Comment: Well I guess we will find out.

Comment: I did switch out the optical drive, didn't help. Once I get some extra cash Ill order a new optical drive.